# Java, GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Hi i am trying to resize the image icon which i tried to use the getScaled method but it's not working, i have attached a copy of the code below.

```
public Example (){
        JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("gui/CheckLib.png")));
        Image resize = l.getScaled(200, 180, 18);
        l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resize));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(l);
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working?

Answer (score 3):

Some research would have shown you that [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) does not have a method called `getScaled`

Some more research would have lead you to [`Image#getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Some more research might have lead you to [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Which might have lead you to [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

Now remember, [`ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) wraps a `java.awt.Image` in an `Icon` interface

Answer (score 1):

You can try Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). It will resize the image based on the space available to the icon.